# Call MVC2 action controller from Webforms class code-behind

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms

Is it possible for a Webforms class to call an MVC2 action controller that returns a string?

My Webforms class is a proxy class for an external webservice, and so I have no JavaScript code - the properties thatI need must be retrieved in the code-behind!

The proxy class is in use by other projects in my solution, so I preferably do not want to move it into the MVC project. The proxy gathers a few properties, among them the full path to a PDF.

The PDF has not yet been generated when the proxy needs it, and the responsibility of generating it lies on the MVC project. Because of this, I need to call an action controller that generates a PDF and returns its path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use the WebRequest class, which MSDN has a good article on here:
[How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really mix webforms and MVC. Better to put them in separate apps & communicate via HTTP/REST/SOAP, etc.

If it's an external web service, can you not add it again to your MVC app?

If you can't modify the proxy at all, then add a webforms page to your mvc app & have it inherit from the proxy. create the controller & action to create the pdf the redirect back to the webform.

Simon

Comment: Are there no alternatives to using HTTP/REST/SOAP? I want to avoid adding another project to the solution if I can. There's numerous other webforms projects that use the proxy, so I do not want to move it to the MVC project.

Comment: It depends on what the proxy is doing. Without further information it's hard to provide a solution. Can you describe what the proxy does in more detail?

Comment: Added a more detailed solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I do not want to bring any knowledge of the proxy into the MVC project. I found another solution.